# How is the derivative in this ReLU backpropagation being calculated? (Neural Network)

Tags: neural-network, computer-science, backpropagation, derivative, relu

The "dvalue" variable is what I'm hung up on... I understand the derivative of the ReLU.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8D2k.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BGHT.png)

Comment: Can you give more information? What dvalue?

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the picture links but they should be visible now.